# Why I'm not able to change id demo's inner html here?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="names" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="getinputs(document.getElementByName(firstname),document.getElementByName(secondname))">
  Your name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Your crush's name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="secondname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <br>
</form>


<script>
function getinputs(one, two)
{
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=one+two;
}
</script>
```

How should I change this to make it work as intuitive?
I want to pass both the values through the form.

Answer (score 2):

Get your elements by id and prevent form submission. See below:

```js
function getinputs(one, two) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=one+two;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="names" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="getinputs(document.getElementById('firstname').value,document.getElementById('secondname').value)">
    Your name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
    Your crush's name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="secondname" id="secondname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <br>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qL0m7px2/

Comment: Why using IDs when question talks about using "name", it can be done using name too.

Answer (score 1):

this approach will not wait for the script to be executed on form submit, and the form will be submitted. If you want to execute js code on submit of the form, you need to make the foll. changes

```
<form name="names" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return getinputs(document.getElementByName(firstname),document.getElementByName(secondname))">

----
----

</form>
```

And then the script:

```
<script>
function getinputs(one, two)
{
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=one+two;
return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace your code with

```
function getinputs() {
   var form = document.querySelector('#form-id');
   document.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML =
       form.firstname.value + form.secondname.value;
}
```

Comment: Not working! Any change that you would like to make?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Hope it will help.

```html
<html>
<body>
<form name="names" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return getinputs()">
  Your name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="firstname"><br>
  Your crush's name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="secondname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <br>
</form>


<script>
function getinputs()
{
var one=document.getElementById("firstname");
var two=document.getElementById("secondname");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=one.value+two.value;
return false;
}
</script>
<p id="demo" ></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make following changes

- **getElementByName** should be **getElementsByName**
- **document.getElementsByName('firstname')[0].value**

  ```
  <script>
  function getinputs(one, two)
  {   
      event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=one+ " " + two;
  }
  </script>

  <p id="demo"></p>
  <form name="names" action="" method="POST" onSubmit="getinputs(document.getElementsByName('firstname')[0].value, document.getElementsByName('secondname')[0].value)">
    Your name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Your crush's name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="secondname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <br>
  </form>
  ```